# Получить список таблиц в пользовательских БД в SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Добрый день. Подскажите запрос на получение списка таблиц пользовательских (не системных) баз данных в SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

//Выдает все базы данных на сервере
SELECT name FROM sys.databases

//Выдает все таблицы в Базе данных
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type in (N'U')

Comment: Второй запрос возвращает список таблиц из СИСТЕМНОЙ базы master.
Наверное я неправильно сформулировал вопрос:
Нужно получать список таблиц из баз, которые созданы пользователем, т.е. создана база БАЗА1 с таблицами ТАБЛИЦА1, ТАБЛИЦА2 и т.д. Нужно получить список этих таблиц: ТАБЛИЦА1, ТАБЛИЦА2

Comment: Второй запрос выведет вам таблицы из базы данных, которую вы выберите.
USE [MyDataBase]  
для выбора базы данных

Comment: Если я помог вам - примите ответ. Под пальцами есть галочка серая. нажмете - зеленая станет

Comment: Извените забыл отметить

Answer (score 11):

Есть ещё вариант SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

Он более кроссплатформенный относительно СУБД, т.к. INFORMATION_SCHEMA является частью стандарта SQL, а sys.objects нет.

Хотя там есть не всё, многие вещи без представлений из схемы sys не получить.

Comment: Запомню, спасибо